# problems with the disabled buttons in the new design

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

In the review queue, when a button is disabled the text is not really clear.
I was able to reproduce this in the "First posts" queue.
IN the image below, the "I'm Done" button is not really visible.
I don't know if this is relevant but I'm using chrome.
Didn't try on other browsers.
[image]

Comment: Same issue on Firefox for me.

Comment: Same for me. Also, before system used to tell me if there are any review available for me at top bar, but not any more.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri reviews available still showing for me

Comment: yeah, it is showing for me now too. Not sure that was only me in that time.

Comment: This is what I am talking about: http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1051017/b89054a76d2781f137d3255d1b22f387 Not sure if it is normal behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for letting us know. This has been corrected.